# Generating correct Url inside HtmlHelper Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagination, html-helper

I have built a crude HTML Helper method with the aim of creating two pagination links (Next and Previous).

Below is the code for the ViewModel (DTO) being passed to the Helper Method:

```
public class PaginationVM
{
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages
    {
        get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / ItemsPerPage); }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the HTML Helper Method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Paginator(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, PaginationVM pInfo)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    var nextPage = pInfo.CurrentPage + 1;
    var prevPage = pInfo.CurrentPage - 1;

    if (pInfo.CurrentPage < pInfo.TotalPages)
    {
        TagBuilder tagA = new TagBuilder("a");
        tagA.MergeAttribute("href", "page/" + nextPage);
        tagA.InnerHtml = "Prev";
        tagA.AddCssClass("prev");
        result.Append(tagA.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        TagBuilder tagB = new TagBuilder("a");
        tagB.MergeAttribute("href", "page/" + prevPage);
        tagB.InnerHtml = "Next";
        tagB.AddCssClass("next");
        result.Append(tagB.ToString());
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
}
```

The above combination of code seems to work, but only from the homepage, if I click the Prev link [ localhost:xxxx/page/2 ], and go to page 2, then the links become [ localhost:xxxx/page/page/2 ].

My routing looks as follows

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PagingPosts/param", // Route name
    "page/{pageId}", // /page/3
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", pageId = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new { pageId = @"\d+" } // Constraints: pageId must be numerical
);
```

As you can see the word page is now duplicated. I can think of a way for fixing this problem, and that is to tell it to generate an ActionLink from the root, and build my URL that way, but I'm not sure how to do that in the HTML helper, and what the best way to do it would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way is to define a helper that takes a `Func<int, string>` delegate that can be passed the page number and return the generated URL string. This way, the paginator helper is not bound to any particular routing and can be reused across your application easily.

Something like

```
public static MvcHtmlString Paginator(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                                      PaginationVM pInfo, 
                                      Func<int, string> pageUrl)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    if (pInfo.TotalPages > 1)
    {
        TagBuilder tag;

        // previous link
        if (pInfo.CurrentPage > 1)
        {
            tag = new TagBuilder("a");
            tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(pInfo.CurrentPage - 1));
            tag.AddCssClass("Prev");
            tag.InnerHtml = "previous";

            result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
        }

        // numbered links
        for (int i = 1; i <= pInfo.TotalPages; i++)
        {
            if (i == pInfo.CurrentPage)
            {
                tag = new TagBuilder("span");
            }
            else 
            {
                tag = new TagBuilder("a");
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
            }

            tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();

            result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
        }

        // next page link
        if (pInfo.CurrentPage < pInfo.TotalPages)
        {
            tag = new TagBuilder("a");
            tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(pInfo.CurrentPage + 1));
            tag.AddCssClass("Next");
            tag.InnerHtml = "next";
            result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
        }
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
}
```

Now in your view, you would use it like

```
@Html.Paginator(pageInfo, pageId => Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { pageId }))
```

Comment: +1, I was just about to post an answer that looked almost identical to this. The only thing I would mention in addition is how to make the URL's look like /Page2 VS /?page=2 with the addition of a new route.

Comment: @Jesse - yep, how the routing is defined is a whole other kettle of fish :)

Comment: Thank You for the quick reply Russ Cam. Two things, can you please briefly explain how [ Fun<int, string> ] works ? I looked at Microsoft's documentation for Delegate, but it is so complex to understand. :( Also I've copied your code and now my links look like this [localhost:xxxx/?page=2] instead of this [localhost:xxxx/page/2] ! My routing is setup [like this](http://pastebin.com/gUXLSjJn).

Comment: @Ciwan - `Func<int, string>` is like a method signature for a method that takes an `int` and returns a `string`. In the usage example above, we pass a lambda expression as the second argument for the `Func<int, string>` parameter that the Paginator method takes. The lambda expression takes a `page` parameter, passes it to `Url.Action()` which returns a string (the resulting URL). The `page` parameter type is strongly typed to be an `int` as this is inferred from the implicit conversion of the lambda expression to the strongly typed `Func<int, string>` delegate. So...

Comment: the incremented int `i` from the loop inside the Paginator method is passed to the `Func<int,string>` method passed into the Paginator method, which gets bound to the `page` parameter of the lambda expression and returns the URL. Does that explain it?

Comment: @Ciwan - now that I've seen your route, I've updated the example usage so you should now get the generated URL that you expect

Comment: **Thank You so much Russ Cam**. It works great, and what's more, I now know what Func<int, string> does, thanks to your explanation.

Comment: @Ciwan - Happy to help :) It's worth taking some time to look at the `Action` and `Func` delegates (including the generic variations), as well as lambda expressions, as they're used all over the place in LINQ. If you really want to grok them, I'd recommend Jon Skeet's excellent C# in Depth. If you sign up to Manning 2012 Countdown, it may come up on offer - http://deals.manningpublications.com/countdown2012.html :)

Comment: Thanks Russ, I've signed up for the CountDown, and I'll get that book for sure. Thank You. :)